# MARIADB/MYSQL : procedure INSERT INTO with timezone change

Tags: timezone, mariadb

I put on mariadb some output ELK with an output jdbc plusgin. Everything works  but source time is UTC and i would like to convert date field into timezone Europe/Paris.

Here's a sample of my INSERT INTO statement :

```
INSERT INTO EventData ( Hour, Provider, Code, Action, Outcome ) VALUES( in_Hour, in_Provider, in_Code, in_Action, in_Outcome );
```

Other Question : is it possible to convert existing hour values to the good timezone?

MariaDB has good timezone.
Hour field is DATETIME format.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is such a function in the sql **CONVERT_TZ**
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/convert_tz/

Comment: Just a comment for example : INSERT INTO EventData ( Hour, Provider, Code, Action, Outcome ) VALUES( CONVERT_TZ(in_Hour,'UTC','Europe/Paris'), in_Provider, in_Code, in_Action, in_Outcome );